# instead of editing the ip each time inside the code, how would i be able to manually enter it through the main script

Tags: python

I'm not too sure on how i would approach this, as i'm not too big on python but i have 2 scripts, and the main script is which controls the others, meaning say i enter 3, i run the portscanner, but i want to be able to manually enter strings through the main script from the portscanner instead of editing the line each time just to scan one address. So the command now is "python portscanner.py 8.8.4.4" but i want to be able to run a ip manually through the mainscript and not have to edit the code like:

```
Choose a number>3
Enter Hostname: 8.8.4.4 or any other random ip
```

anybody have a solution?

- portscanner code: https://ufile.io/cltwd6cx
- picture: https://ibb.co/YPt9pnF

Comment: Use the `input()` function to prompt the user for input and store it in a variable.

Comment: You could use `sys.argv[1]` to get the IP, if you run it from the command line as `python portscanner.py "8.8.4.4"`

Comment: Could you go into detail more?